# creating search engine using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, computer-science

I want to create a search engine in my website using ASP.NET. This engine will search an user's input text from the database (SQL Server 2008). Anyone know how to create this search engine? I really need your help. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
Partial Class Search
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection("server=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Desktop\science\App_Data\Library.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim sqlquery As String = "SELECT DISTINCT packagename,packagecategory FROM package Where "
    If txtTitle.Text <> "" Then
        sqlquery += "packagename LIKE '%" + txtname.Text + "%' AND "
    Else
        sqlquery += "packagename Like '%%' AND "
    End If

    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue <> "Any" Then
        sqlquery += "packagecategory LIKE '%" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "%' AND "
    Else
        sqlquery += "packagecategory Like '%%' AND "
    End If
```

I find the problem in showing the result in the list view...

Comment: A little more explaination of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: please see my coding.. i'm looking for the code to show the result based on my search input..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for an out the box solution.

Answer (score 1):

A way you can speed up your query is to not search for COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%%' because everything will match, basicallyl, remove the elses in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you can get will be to use a db connector, then use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '$USERINPUT'`

Comment: That's true for an exact keyword search. Wrapping `USERINPUT` in percentages would be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Lucene.NET: http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Answer (score 0):

Because you use Sql Server then have a look at [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx), it can help you.

Lucene.net is also the option as Mark has mentioned.